# why difference while using the whois tool?

Tags: domain-name, whois

I just used the whois to see how it works and i searched for a URL, every thing was right but there was a little confusion that when i searched the same url with and without "www" it showed two different ip addresses for them and searching those different ip addresses on the browser brought me same web pages. even when i searched that web address in browser with and without www it also showed same web page.

why is that, if it had to be the same web page then why, with and without www, whois showed not only different ip addresses but also different other information too.

Comment: This would be based on your server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

A domain name WHOIS does not provide IP addresses. It shows ownership information (who owns the domain name and how you can contact them). With or without the `www` part, the domain is the same. For instance, `www.example.com` and `example.com` are both subsets of the `example.com` domain, which belongs to the same person/organization. Hence, the WHOIS reply is identical. *If you are seeing different owner info, please tell us what domains you queried.*

On the other hand, a DNS Lookup provides IP addresses, and it is up to the owner of the domain to decide whether the domain with or without `www.` resolve to the same IP address(es).

As to why going to either URLs give you the same web page, since they belong to the same person/organization, and website visitors in general expect to see the same website with or without `www.`, the owner most likely decided to serve the exact same web pages.